# One word to describe for urge for improvement

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

I am wondering any word that can describe urge for improvement.

I have learnt some of the words like, motivated, ambitious are something related to personal improvement. But it doesn't directly describe a person who urges for improvement. It merely mean he is being motivated/ambitious, therefore they definitely urge for improvement.

Comment: _Ambition_ is the English word that comes closest to what you describe. What does your English language dictionary tell you about this noun? Please use the **[edit]** link to add a sentence to your question with a _______ where the word you are looking for would fit.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, and you are asking about a person who wishes to become better, then you are not using the word **urges** properly.   A coach urges an athlete to improve. The athlete *has the urge* or *feels the urge* to improve.  The athlete is being urged (by the coach) to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no one word, but here are some ways that you could describe somebody who wants to improve.

> Bob has an aspiration for improvement.
>
> Joe seeks improvement.
>
> Matt desires improvement.

If you really want to drive the idea home, you could describe this aspiration with context:

> Dan's aspiration for improvement drives him to work hard and live a conscientious life.

Answer (score 0):

If you need one word, 'Persistent' would be okay.

Persistent is define as continuing firmly or obstinately in a course of action in spite of difficulty or opposition.
Example:
He is persistent in spite of failures at work/school.

Synonyms: stubborn, persevering, gritty.